# Is Great Software Testing all about generating Test Ideas?

Tags: test-management, manual-testing, testcase

In manual testing, how important role do great Test Ideas play? How often do you you fall short of testing ideas. for instance:- you are testing a financial domain web application.

any idea generating technique that has helped testers test better practically. Please share.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit theoretical, so I'll start my answer the same way: In theory, or in some projects, testing can be all about generating the great test ideas that will find the most relevant issues. A bit samy way that in theory, or in some projects systematic way of working with requirements will find all the relevant issues and prove that system works the way it is intended.

For the example, the financial domain, the customer most probably will want to know what has been tested and to what extent. That will meant that with some sort test management practices are needed. When to test ( with the great ideas ), when to re-test, how to work with issues and so on.